# не отображается страница в django Python

Tags: python, django

В Django создаю страницу `'Hello World'` приложения `news`, но отображается ошибка 404:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. admin/
2. news/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.
```

В терминале отображается: `Not Found: /` Однако, когда в браузере вручную набираю адрес `http://127.0.0.1:8000/news`, то всё работает и появляется запись `'Hello world'`. Ошибка появляется как в Yandex browser, так и в Google Chrome. Операционная система Windows 10, Python 3.7.9, Django 3.2.6.

**Операции, которые выполнял с самого начала:**

Создаю папку `\testsite\django-sites`

В программе `ConEmu` активирую виртуальное окружение `.\venv\Scripts\activate`

В командной строке ввожу команду `django-admin startproject mysite`

Перехожу в папку с проектом `cd mysite`

Создаю приложение `python manage.py startapp news`

В папке `views` дописываю:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    print(request)
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

В файле `settings.py` в строке `INSTALLED_APPS` дописываю строку `news.apps.NewsConfig,`

Для указания адреса к нашему созданному приложению в файле `urls.py` дописываю `from news.views import index`

В строку `urlpatterns` дописываю `path('news/', index),`

Запускаю сервер `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Из того, что говорится в ошибке, для джанго, вы пытаетесь зайти через `.../`, а не `.../news/`

Comment: В urls основного приложения вы написали  path('', include('app.urls'))?